# Merge a Spark data frame into an existing ACID transactional Hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, acid

Consider a simple merge statement in Hive:

```
merge into
  base_table A 
using
  merge_from_table B 
on
  (A.id = B.id)
when matched then update set 
  A.lastname = B.lastname
```

Now imagine:

1. base_table is a transactional Hive table (ACID operations
   enabled).
2. instead of merge_from_table we have a data frame that is produced
   in Spark

**Question 1:**
Is there any way to directly merge the data frame into the Hive table?

If the answer to Question 1 is "no", then:

**Question 2:** Right now the best I can think of is to write the data frame into a temporary hive table and then use the above Hive statement to merge into my base_table. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a verification than an answer.

- Assuming you do not use delta format from Databricks

  - and that you do want to re-state the data

    - and that you do not want to use own delta computation in Spark with optimization techniques to limit processing

      - and that you do not want to have the data inserted in a "current" partition

        - then. Spark does not support DDL for updating

          - so your next best solution is indeed the simplest.